# my code give an error if a enter a letter or a charcter different to a float or integer

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

my purpose is to return a message if the user enter a letter or character different to an integer or float but if a enter a letter like "jhdsjfhdhjd"
it give me an error

```
 my_number = int(input("Please ,enter your number here !"))
if my_number is not int:
    print("It is not a number a number !")
else:
    my_num = int(my_number)
    if my_num == 0:
        while my_num < 11 :
            print("Not there Yet , your number is " + str(my_num) + ".We continue increase your number to 10 !")
            my_num +=1
        print("Good, increasing is Done , the number is 10")
    elif my_num > 0:
        while my_num > -1:
            if my_num == 0:
                print("Correct ,the decreasing is finished.The number is 0")
        print("Not there Yet , your number is " + str(my_num)+ ".We continue decrease your number to 0 !")
        my_num -=1
    else:
        print("It isn't a number ,Please enter an integer")
```

Comment: You need to check if the input is numeric `isnumeric()` before converting it to integer or float

Answer (score 0):

The input function captures the typed value as a **string**. You may coerce it to become an integer by using int() but if the entered value is a floating number then you will loose precision.

There could be many ways to differentiate between a string, an integer and a float. You can use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to check if the string is an integer, float or string. Below is one of the possible solutions. Also in your code your are dealing with 0 and > 0 but not dealing with < 0 case ..may be you want to add that part as well. Also you need to modify the logic if the input number is a floating point number.

```py
import re
my_number = input("Please ,enter your number here !")
if not re.fullmatch(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*$', my_number):
    print("It is not a number a number !")
else:
    if re.fullmatch(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*$', my_number):#The input string is an integer
        print("You entered an integer")
        my_num = int(my_number)
    else: #it is a float
        print("You entered a float")
        my_num = float(my_number)
    if my_num == 0.0:
        while my_num < 11 :
            print("Not there Yet , your number is " + str(my_num) + ".We continue increase your number to 10 !")
            my_num +=1
        print("Good, increasing is Done , the number is 10")
    elif my_num > 0:
        while my_num > -1:
            if my_num == 0:
                print("Correct ,the decreasing is finished.The number is 0")
            else:
                print("Not there Yet , your number is " + str(my_num)+ ".We continue decrease your number to 0 !")
            my_num -=1
```

The output for a string is

```
Please ,enter your number here !abcdef
It is not a number a number !
```

The output for 0 is as below.

```py
Please ,enter your number here !0
You entered an integer
Not there Yet , your number is 0.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 1.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 2.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 3.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 4.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 5.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 6.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 7.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 8.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 9.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Not there Yet , your number is 10.We continue increase your number to 10 !
Good, increasing is Done , the number is 10
```

The output for a positive integer is as below

```py
Please ,enter your number here !8
You entered an integer
Not there Yet , your number is 8.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 7.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 6.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 4.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 3.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 2.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 1.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Correct ,the decreasing is finished.The number is 0
```

The output for a floating number is

```py
Please ,enter your number here !6.5
You entered a float
Not there Yet , your number is 6.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 5.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 4.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 3.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 2.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 1.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is 0.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
Not there Yet , your number is -0.5.We continue decrease your number to 0 !
```

All the best.